# Route Multiple APIs with same Domain Name Nginx 404

Tags: networking, server, nginx

I've got a requirement to a setup SSL on port 8080 with allowing user to acces multiple APIs developed and deployed on same server via https,

So I'm using NGINX to develop this SSL + Routing configuration.

This is the **nginx/default.conf**

```
server {
listen 8080 ssl;
server_name api.example.com;

ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/api_example_com.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/api_example_com.key;

location / {
   proxy_pass http://192.168.100.12:4000;
}

location /web/ {
   proxy_pass http://192.168.100.12:4000;
}

location /admin/ {
  proxy_pass http://192.168.100.12:5000;
}
```

}

Currently, **api.example.com** is working correctly and I could access the API which runs on 4000 port via **api.example.com**.

But **api.example.com/web** and **api.example.com/admin** giving 404 with following error on console,

`22/Dec/2020:19:20:07 +0000] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36"`

Comment: did you check what you get in web browser using directly `http://192.168.100.12:4000/web/` `http://192.168.100.12:5000`, `http://192.168.100.12:5000/admin/`

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue with adding / end of proxy_pass URL

```
proxy_pass http://192.168.100.12:4000/;
```

Comment: Yeah if you don't provide a / then it passes the requested URI (`/admin`, `/web`, etc.) to the request, when you add the `/` to the proxy_pass, you end up telling it what URI to route to.  Was writing that in an answer then you posted :P  (writing posts via phone is pain)